# How do I request re-login from PHP script using client ssl certificate?

Tags: php, nginx, client-certificates

I have several client certificates on the client machine, and once I logged in to the site using one of them, the server remembers me.
How do I force server to stop remembering me and to ask for a certificate again (I want to authenticate with another cert).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I force server to stop remembering me and to ask for a certificate again

This makes no sense.

If the server is "remembering" you in the absence of any certificate then there's something very wrong with your authentication mechanism.

It's more likely that the **browser** is remembering which certificate you use for that site.

Answer (score 1):

symcbean is right, is a client-side issue.
[This thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-webid/2011Jul/0120.html) is relevant to the "log-out" issue when dealing with ssl sessions. the following javascript snippet is quoted, and working for ie/ff.

```
    function logout() {
      if (document.all == null) // FF, Opera, etc
        {  if (window.crypto) window.crypto.logout();
           else alert('no window.crypto')}      
      else // MSIE 6+
        {  document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');};     
     }
    function login() {
      if (document.all == null) // FF, Opera, etc
        {   if (window.crypto) window.crypto.logout();
            else alert('no window.crypto')
        }      
      else // MSIE 6+
        {  alert('login in msie') 
           document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');};     
     }
```

Comment: Links are not answers.  If that link goes dead (server goes down, etc), then your answer becomes useless.  Can you edit in relevant content from the linked page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a client-side functionality. PHP wouldn't be able to handle it.